# Typescript Enum combined key value issue

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I would like implement `enum` in my drop-down but I get both key and value in list.

My enum:

```
export enum VMRole {
    "Kubemaster" = 0, "Kubeworker" = 1, "Other" = 2
}
```

My class I am trying to assign `enum` to my property:

```
export class VirtualMachine {   
    role: VMRole;
    ...
}
```

My Component:

```
export class AddVmComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {};
  @ViewChild('addVMForm', { static: false }) formValues;  


  constructor(private alertify: AlertifyService, private vm: VmService, private route: 
       ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.model.role = Object.keys(VMRole).filter(p => typeof p !== 'number')
  }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<select [ngModel]="model.role" class="form-control">     
   <option disabled>-Please choose role-</option>       
   <option *ngFor="let data of model.role | keyvalue"> 
            {{data.value}} 
   </option> 
</select>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is happening when you try to filter out the numbers from your `enum` with `p => typeof p !== 'number'`. Just tested out what it gives back where the values represented just like the following array - As you can see the array contains only `string` values:

[image: values]

So the solution looks tricky but it does the job for you:

```
Object.keys(VMRole).filter(p => !Number.isInteger(parseInt(p)))
```

Or even easier solution which also works fine for TypeScript:

```
Object.keys(VMRole).filter(p => isNaN(p as any))
```

Please read further here:

1. [Number.isInteger()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)
2. [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
3. [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Tried second approach works like charm. You are saved my day. Thanks!!